# Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced

Tags: pdftex, r, sweave

we are executing following code from .php file.

$result1 = shell_exec("R CMD Sweave /var/www/html/r/r_latex_sweave.Rnw");

$result2 = shell_exec("pdflatex /var/www/html/r/r_latex_sweave.tex");

But, we are getting this errors :

**$result1 = shell_exec("R CMD Sweave /var/www/html/r/r_latex_sweave.Rnw");
[11:53:55]  $result2 = shell_exec("pdflatex /var/www/html/r/r_latex_sweave.tex");**

can you please help us on this?

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125995/19326 also where is the errormessage, that does not look like an error message to me

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! Have a look at [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format.