# Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced in php file

Tags: errors, pdftex, r, sweave

We are using following code in `.php` script for generate `.pdf` file.

```
$result1 = exec("R CMD Sweave /var/www/html/r/r_latex_sweave.Rnw");

$result2 = exec("pdflatex /var/www/html/r/r_latex_sweave.tex");
```

but, we are getting this errors when we are executing `.Rnw` and `.tex` files.

**! I can't write on file `r_latex_sweave.log'.
Please type another transcript file name: 
! Emergency stop
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!**

Note: We have `.tex` and `.Rnw` folder in `/var/www/html` folder?

Comment: sounds like there is a writelock on the file. Ensure that pdflatex if called from the shell works. After that see if the webserver has the proper permissions. Depending on your setup the file has to be owned by a special user under which the webserver runs, so the webserver may change it. Since this seems more like a server/programming question I suggest [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) or [superuser](http://superuser.com)

Comment: Delete `r_latex_sweave.log` file from directory. This file was builded by you as a user of the system, and php(`_www` user) have no permissions to rewrite it.